# The option modal: true in magnificpopup not works

Tags: javascript, magnific-popup

I'm trying to set to the current instance of the magnific-popup the option - modal: true, and it does not work. when I look at it in the console it says "modal: true" but the popup does not behave like that

````
    ```$.magnificPopup.instance.st.modal = true
    console.log($.magnificPopup.instance.st.modal)
    ```
````

Comment: please share enough code to understand and reproduce the problem

Comment: It's a magnificpopup that read a card - the user cannot do anything until the callback so I want it'll be a modal (This is a shortcut to set closeOnContentClick, closeOnBgClick, showCloseBtn, and enableEscapeKey to false.) and when we get the callback the popup will be back to normal.
'''active: function() {
    $.magnificPopup.instance.st.modal = true
}
deactivate: function() {
     $.magnificPopup.instance.st.modal = false
}''' .   Thank you!!